# Get a Kinect JointType by its ID number instead of its name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk

Is there anyway to retrieve a "joint type" by its value, instead of by its name?

For example, instead of `(joints[JointType.ShoulderRight]);`, we write `(joints[8]);`.

According to [JointType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointtype.aspx), when I do the latter, it gives me the following error

> Cannot convert from 'int' to 'Microsoft.Kinect.JointType'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I use in my sources.

You just need to do a cast :

```
JointType myJoint;
myJoint = (JointType)8;
```

after that you can write:

```
(joints[myJoint]);
```